# Put labels at the column separators of a table

Tags: tables

I have created a table like this:

[image]

I want to add some text right below the column separators like this:

[image]

How do I go about that? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\mk}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|}\hline
    a + b + c + d + e & a + b + c + d & a + b + c & a + b & a \\\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}   &\multicolumn{1}{!{\mk{0.01}}c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{!{\mk{0.05}}c}{}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`!{something}` preserves the `\tabcolsep` and inserts the content in between. Fore more on this refer to `array` manual.